# Secondary constructor initiation logic

Tags: kotlin, generics, constructor

I have a generic data class like:

```
data class ConfigurationDTO<T : Any>(
    val id: Long,
    val key: String,
    var value: T
)
```

And I would like to have a constructor where I could pass the `value` as `String` and a `KClass` to deserialize it. The problem is Kotlin oblies me to call `this()` on the secondary constructor and I have no value for `value` yet:

```
   constructor(id: Long, key: String, valueStr: String, klazz: KClass<T>)
       : this(id, key, ??????)
```

What I would like to do is the equivalent like:

```
   // Doesn't work
   constructor(id: Long, key: String, valueStr: String, klazz: KClass<T>) {
       val value = // Deserialize, initialize logic with valueSTR and klazz...
       this(id, key, value)
   }
```

So, processing the parameters before calling the constructor.
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Where is `deserialize` declared in?

Comment: Hi Sweeper, it's just pseudocode... I can instantiate an `ObjectMapper` and use it, doesn't really seem to matter for the point of the question 

Comment: In that case, can't you just do it inline? For example: `: this(id, key, deserialize(valueStr, klazz))`. You don't need `value` there.

Comment: It does but then I need to pass in the deserialization logic as well (being the object mapper or whatever). Isn't there a simplier and more direct way? This seems to be an usual need...

Comment: What do you mean by "simplier and more direct"? How is `: this(id, key, deserialize(valueStr, klazz))` not simple enough and not direct enough? If you have multiple statements you want to run, put everything in a `run` block. `: this(id, key, run { ... })` Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I mean if I do it like that, who is calling `ConfigurationDTO` is resposible for throwin in the `deserialize` logic as well. I would like `ConfigurationDTO` to solve it by itself, not needing a parameter for deserialization. For example, if I use `objectMapper` to deserialize I need to call it like `ConfigurationDTO(id, key, valueStr, klass, objectMapper)` so I can use this `objectMapper` in the `this()` call. The `run` block might solve it, let me check

Comment: Nah, `Cannot access run before superclass constructor has been called`. Cannot use `run` on `this()`

Comment: Huh, overload resolution kinda sucks here. You'd need to write `kotlin.run` to call the global function.

Comment: Ok, that did work, thanks :) 
Won't lie, it still seems hacky to me, but it is what it is. Thanks Sweeper

Comment: You can always use a factory method instead of a constructor. The class's companion object is the best place for that; and if you define it `operator fun invoke(…)` then calling it _looks_ just like calling a constructor. Advantages include: being able to do arbitrary processing before calling a constructor, being able to return a cached instance, being able to return a subclass instance, and being able to give it a meaningful name (e.g. if you have multiple factory methods taking the same parameter types). The only down-side is that subclasses constructors can't call it.